# Basic function call in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

If I write following code, I get "Hello World", but not "Hey from function". What am I doing wrong? Same if I try to write to console from called function. Seems it is not called.

This is very basic testing of node.js

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

function writetest(req, res) {
    res.send("Hey from function");
}


app.get('/nodejs/', function(req, res) { 
    res.send('Hello World!');
    writetest(req,res);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

No error messages, it just seems not to call he function.

Comment: What happens if you remove the first call to `res.send('Hello World!')`? Perhaps the you can't call `.send` on the response, twice?

Comment: Also, did you stop your server and restart after making your code changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `res.write()` and you have to call `res.end()` at the end.

Because `res.send()` calls `res.end()` internally and you can't write to `res` anymore

Comment: Thank you @RamiJarrar and others all for comments! res.write() (along with res.end() in the end of calling funtion) was the correct way to do it

Answer (score 2):

`res.send` can only be called once, once the data is sent, the users browser is not waiting for any more responses. What you are trying to achieve can be done with `res.write` and `res.end`, detailed [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/all.html#response.write).
An example of how to use it is shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You cant execute`res.send` twice in one api call.You can use `if else` loop to do such operation but at the same time two `res.send` cant execute.